# Python: How to read and change multiple numbers in a file without using .split

Tags: python, file, io

This is my code for trying to read in the file's numbers

```
def process_body(infile, outfile, modification):
'''
changing the numbers to the outfile              
'''

for line in infile.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    num = ""
    space = " "

    if modification == "negate": 
        for char in line:
            input() #The file is really big this is here to go line by line for decoding
            if char != space:
                num += char

            neg = negate(num)
            print(neg)

            if char == space:
                pass
```

I am unsure what to do when char equals space, because space is unable to be negated in the negate function which is

```
def negate(num):
'''
absolute value of RGB value - 255
'''

num = int(num)
negate_line = num - 255
negate_line = abs(negate_line)
negate_line = str(negate_line)
return negate_line
```

here are a few lines from the input file

```
0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 1 45 90 
1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 92 1 45 92 
1 45 92 0 46 92 0 46 92 0 47 93 0 47 93
```

According to the teachers instructions I am not aloud to use any string methods other than .strip. I am unable to use .split in this assignment, due to the fact it would make it really easy. Any help or trips would be greatly appreciated, I've been at this task for a few days now I can't seem to get it to quite work.

Comment: can you use slicing - `line[0:1]`, `line[2:4]`, etc ?

Comment: I think so, but some of the lines in the input file have more numbers than others for example

`0 53 97 0 53 97 0 53 97 0 53 97 0 54 101 

0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 

0 54 101 0 54 101 1 55 101 1 55 101 1 55 101 
1 55 101 0 54 100 0 54 100 0 53 99 0 53 99 
`

So unless there was a way to accommodate this,  I don't know if it would work

Comment: Well you can't really tell with that post, but some of the lines have extra digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine on the test input you provided:

```
with open('ip', 'rb') as f:
  for line in f:
    char = ""
    for c in line.strip():
      if c != " ":
        char += c
      else:
        print abs(int(char) - 255)
        char = ""
```

You can add the if statements yourself. Also, you don't need to convert an int into a str if you just want to print it.

Comment: With the code I am currently running, I am getting an error 

`    num = int(num)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 4'
`

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe there is another way**, instead of doing a lot of computations, that always will yield the same 256 different results, do it one time for all the computations. Sometimes when stuck on a problem, reverse it, do it the other way around.

```
def main():
    converter = {str(x): str(abs(x-255)) for x in range(256)}
    s = ["0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 1 45 90",
         "1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 92 1 45 92",
         "1 45 92 0 46 92 0 46 92 0 47 93 0 47 93"]

    for line in s:
        num = ""
        new_line = []
        for c in line:
            if c == " ":
                new_line += [converter[num]]
                num = ""
            else:
                num += c

        print(" ".join(new_line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```